# How to create a custom function in xaml for binding properties when a value is null?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

If a value is null I want to display the other value and display a other labeltext. How to do that in WPF/XAML without altering the underlying data-layer?

```
// Some pseudo-code 
      if a != null 
        my label = a 
        my value = a 
        else 
        my label = b 
        my value = b
```

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="7" Margin="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="my label"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontWeight="Normal" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="13.333" />

<TextBlock Grid.Column="8" Margin="5,-0.002,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="my value"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="13.333" FontWeight="Bold" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [binding converters](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-binding-converters)

Binding coverter recieves the value that has to be binded **before** binding mechanism assigns it to a control/property. In the functions of that class you can make conversion/transformation between actual model value (for example) and the value that appears on UI. Mainly converters are used for conversion between different *types*: on model you have `false` on ui should have `red` *color*, instead. So you should successfully acieve your goals using that.